# How can I make custom validation class generic in asp.net (if property 1 is true, property 2 is required)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, customvalidator

I am using .NET Core and have the following code in a view model:

```
public bool IsLocalArrangement { get; set; }
[RequiredIfLocalArrangements]
public string LocalArrangementDetail { get; set; }
```

For this annotation to work, I created a new class, and have the following code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using MyProject.ViewModels;

namespace MyProject.Validation
{
    public class RequiredIfLocalArrangements : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
                                                    ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var vm = (ArrangementsViewModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value) && vm.IsLocalArrangement ?
                new ValidationResult("Please provide details for the local arrangement(s)")
                    : ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }

}
```

However this scenario is coming up a lot, and I'm now replicating all this code to new classes (RequiredIfOwnsVehicle, etc.), where the only variables I need to change are the view model name, the boolean property within the view model that it depends on, and the validation result message.

How can I make this generic?

EDIT:
In trying to explore the foolproof project from github I run into this issue with System.Web.Mvc

[image]

Comment: Use a `[RequiredIf("otherPropertyName", true)]` attribute. There are plenty of examples of it including the [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) library

Comment: And if you want to write your own conditional validation attributes that also give client side validation, I recommend reading [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry I forgot to mention I am using .NET Core, I explored foolproof a few weeks ago and ran into issues because of this

Comment: That will not make any difference. What issues were you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think I remember incompatible nuget packages with core and I think I eventually read there was no intention to upgrade it for use with core so I lost hope for it. I've tried to open the project from github and have included a screenshot of my most recent issue as an edit.

Comment: Looks like that is due to the incompatible `System.Web.Mvc` reference. I'll create a Gist shortly that should get you started

Comment: Refer [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/stephenmuecke/e71c9fc6d16b935c9b67c8a772e571c3). Its from my own conditional validation library. I have commented out the the code that generates client side validation - that part is different in core-mvc - and I'll try and find a link for you later to explain how to modify it for core-mvc

Comment: @StephenMuecke great! I managed to get this working. I'll update my question later :)

Comment: Refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) - the section on _Custom validation_. The difference is that the `ValidationAttribute` implements `IClientModelValidator` rather than `IClientValidatable`. As for the script for client side validation, refer [here](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-conditionalvalidation/blob/master/scripts/sandtrap-unobtrusive-validation-v2.0.js)